# Creating single executable file with cx freeze for .py files

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a python program and want to compile it to .exe file in python 3.6.

As pynput is not yet supported for python 3.6, I used cx freeze.

It compiles the program without any error but the problem I'm getting is, I want to compile my .py program into only one single .exe file, but cx freeze creates a build folder with lots of folders in it. Without those folders, the exe file is not running.

How to solve this?

Comment: try using pyinstaller it has the option of --onefile

Comment: Does pyinstaller supports python 3.6?

Comment: yes. http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

> cx_Freeze does not support building a single file exe, where all of
>   the libraries for your application are embedded in one executable
>   file.

So, I'll advice you to use pyinstaller.

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller -y -F  pythonfile.py
```

Or if you prefer gui try auto-py-to-exe

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```